# Apply an iteration over class method and apply links in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class Location. What I'd like to do is in my footer do something like:

```
<%= Location.all.each do |location| %>
 <ul class="footer-nav" id="foot">
  <li class="footer-list">
   <%= link_to location.name, location_path(location.name), class: "footer-location"%>
     </li>
```

The problem is that since I'm pulling the class method it's giving me EVERYTHING. So to get around that I tried creating the following helper:

```
def footer
  Location.all.map(&:name).join(',')
end
```

This will actually clear everything out and give me a list of the location names but. How do I iterate over and then apply the links to those locations? Or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: `x.each` returns `x` so you probably don't want `<%= ... %>` for this, just `<% ... %>`. That could be why you're getting "EVERYTHING".

Comment: Your `location_path` accepts a name, not an id?

Comment: Yeah it was simply a matter of switching it out so I'm not outputting everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%=` outputs the return value of the statement it contains to the HTML document. `<%` executes the statement but doesn't output anything to the document.

`<%= Location.all.each { |l| ... } %>`, therefore, will output the return value of `Location.all.each` to the document, which is an iterable collection of `Location`s. Assuming you only want the HTML you've put inside the block to be displayed, simply drop the `=`:

```
<% Location.all.each do |location| %>
  <ul class="footer-nav" id="foot">
    <li class="footer-list">
      <%= link_to location.name, location_path(location.name), class: "footer-location"%>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```